# setting cookie and unable to read them in different php file

Tags: php, cookies

I have a small application and now it is time to include a login game on top of everything. Just got it up and running on the real world ( :P )

Here is my code on login page (login.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Login
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">



    <?php
            if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']))
            {
                if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
                {
                    $secret = '';
                    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
                    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

                    if($responseData->success)
                    {                   
                        $user = $_POST['user'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];

                        $salt = "d5f332312e3e390c81f6ef9f242c21bf9e472d6296ddd4bebddd0f54eb576f14";


                        $hpassword = hash('sha256', $salt . $password);

                        $_COOKIE['user'] = $user;
                        $_COOKIE['pass'] = $hpassword;

                        $auth = 1;
                        $_COOKIE['authorized'] = $auth;



                        setrawcookie("user", $user, time() + 28800, "/",'domaindig.eu');
                        setrawcookie("hpass", $hpassword, time() + 28800, "/",'domaindig.eu');
                        setrawcookie("authorized", $auth, time() + 28800, "/",'domaindig.eu');

                        print_r($_COOKIE);

                        header( 'Location: check.php');
                    }
                }
            }
    ?>

    username: <input name="user" type="user"><br>
    password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you may see, I used google recaptcha i order to prevent brute force logins. As of that time (when i inserted repcatcha), none of my $_SESSION variables worked ever again. So, I decided to work with cookies (new experiance, due to always use of sessions).

So far, so good.

When I finished coding this php page, I moved on finishing php file, check.php. In this file I check the credentials and if everything checks out, I redirect to main page and menu (without any graphs yes, only pure php).

My problem is:

On the second file, I can't see any cookie. I use print_r($_COOKIE); and I see only cookies from recaptcha. On login page, I see the 3 cookies that I am trying to set, but on the other files, it seems I cannot read them. I checked multiple browsers and multiple computers, but with the same luck. I have verify, that the browsers can accept cookies, but it seems I have made a mistake.

If something is foggy about my description, please let me know, and I will clarify.

Here is my check.php code (which checks the credentials using cookies):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        check
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
    <form action="check.php" method="POST">

        <?php
        if ($_COOKIE['authorized'] == 1)
        {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['user']) || isset($_COOKIE['hpass']))
            {
                require('ConnectToDB.php');

                $username = $_COOKIE['user'];
                $password = $_COOKIE['hpass'];

                $result="SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'";
                $tbl=mysqli_query ($conn, $result);

                $table = $tbl->fetch_assoc();
                $pass = $table['password'];

                if ($pass)
                {
                    if ($password == $pass)
                    {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
                        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                        $result = "INSERT INTO `logins` ( `username`, `date`, `ip`) VALUES ('$username', '$date', '$ip')";
                        $tbl = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
                        $_COOKIE['authorized'] = 1;
                        echo "Login successfull! Redirecting.";


                        require 'ConnectToDB.php';

                        $alphanumeric[0] = "0";
                        $alphanumeric[1] = "1";
                        $alphanumeric[2] = "2";
                        $alphanumeric[3] = "3";
                        $alphanumeric[4] = "4";
                        $alphanumeric[5] = "5";
                        $alphanumeric[6] = "6";
                        $alphanumeric[7] = "7";
                        $alphanumeric[8] = "8";
                        $alphanumeric[9] = "9";
                        $alphanumeric[10] = "a";
                        $alphanumeric[11] = "b";
                        $alphanumeric[12] = "c";
                        $alphanumeric[13] = "d";
                        $alphanumeric[14] = "e";
                        $alphanumeric[15] = "f";
                        $alphanumeric[16] = "g";
                        $alphanumeric[16] = "h";
                        $alphanumeric[17] = "i";
                        $alphanumeric[18] = "j";
                        $alphanumeric[19] = "k";
                        $alphanumeric[20] = "l";
                        $alphanumeric[21] = "m";
                        $alphanumeric[22] = "n";
                        $alphanumeric[23] = "o";
                        $alphanumeric[24] = "p";
                        $alphanumeric[25] = "q";
                        $alphanumeric[26] = "r";
                        $alphanumeric[27] = "s";
                        $alphanumeric[28] = "t";
                        $alphanumeric[29] = "u";
                        $alphanumeric[30] = "v";
                        $alphanumeric[31] = "w";
                        $alphanumeric[32] = "x";
                        $alphanumeric[33] = "y";
                        $alphanumeric[34] = "z";
                        $alphanumeric[35] = "A";
                        $alphanumeric[36] = "B";
                        $alphanumeric[37] = "C";
                        $alphanumeric[38] = "D";
                        $alphanumeric[39] = "E";
                        $alphanumeric[40] = "F";
                        $alphanumeric[41] = "G";
                        $alphanumeric[42] = "H";
                        $alphanumeric[43] = "I";
                        $alphanumeric[44] = "J";
                        $alphanumeric[45] = "K";
                        $alphanumeric[46] = "L";
                        $alphanumeric[47] = "M";
                        $alphanumeric[48] = "N";
                        $alphanumeric[49] = "O";
                        $alphanumeric[50] = "P";
                        $alphanumeric[51] = "Q";
                        $alphanumeric[52] = "R";
                        $alphanumeric[53] = "S";
                        $alphanumeric[54] = "T";
                        $alphanumeric[55] = "U";
                        $alphanumeric[56] = "V";
                        $alphanumeric[57] = "W";
                        $alphanumeric[58] = "X";
                        $alphanumeric[59] = "Y";
                        $alphanumeric[60] = "Z";

                        global $session;
                        $session = "";

                        for ($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
                        {
                            $rnd = rand(0, 60);
                            $session .= $alphanumeric[$rnd];
                        }


                        $date = date("Y-m-d");
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

                        $result = "INSERT INTO `sessions` ( `user`, `date`, `session_id`, `ip`, `login`) VALUES ('$username', '$date', '$session', '$ip', '1')";
                        $tbl = mysqli_query($conn, $result);                            

                        echo "All done";
                        echo '<script> window.location = "https://domaindig.eu/index.php" </script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "User found but password provided was wrong. Try again!";
                    //  echo '<script> window.location = "https://domaindig.eu/login.php" </script>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Failure. Couldn't fetch password!!! Try again.";
                    //echo '<script> window.location = "https://domaindig.eu/login.php" </script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Something went wrong. Try login again!";
                //echo '<script> window.location = "https://domaindig.eu/login.php" </script>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unauthorized access!!";
            //echo '<script> window.location = "https://domaindig.eu/login.php" </script>';
        }

        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are also a picture of my cookies when I show them on login page:

[image]

I thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to make sure that the two PHP files are in the same hosts.
Beacuse cookie can only be get in the same host,not ip.

For example:
you put the login.php into your website,user user use this address logining:

> localhost/login

then,the user can visit this address to get his cookie:

> localhost/analyticstracking

Comment: all files, are in the same domain name, and in the same directory ( / )

Comment: I run your code in my host just now , I can get cookies.Please make sure you visit the two php file in the same domain.

Comment: Hello. This does work, but if you combine the above code with google recaptcha, sessions does not work, but I hoped cookies wold work. Have you tried the code with recaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours to find a solution and then I accidently did this and it worked!

**Before**

```
setcookie("name", "value", 1 * 30 * 24 * 3600, "/");
```

**After**

```
setcookie("name", "value", time() + 1 * 30 * 24 * 3600, "/");
```

I just added time() function to it. Really weird!

Answer (score -1):

Try to set Cookie directory:

```js
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+86400, '/');
```